# Role of JAXB in Java based Web Services

Tags: service, jaxb, web, axis

I must admit that I'm new to Web services.  When I create a Web service using CXF or Axis, even with custom beans being used to communicate information between the client and the service, the objects are automatically marshalled and unmarshalled for me (I mean CXF or Axis create all the necessary files and classes).  So, even though I know JAXB is used by the stack to marshal, and unmarshal objects, but I don't directly need to work with JAXB.

Now, my question is whether I need to work with JAXB directly, as far as Web services are concerned, or that marshaling and unmarshalling will always be handled for me?

Answer (score 10):

When creating a JAX-WS (SOAP) or JAX-RS (RESTful) Web Service, JAXB is used as the binding layer to convert objects to/from XML (and sometimes JSON).  This marshalling/unmarshalling is triggered automatically for you.  Where you interact with JAXB is by adding annotations to your domain model to control how the XML looks.  Below are a couple of examples that you may find useful:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html (JAX-WS example)
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html (JAX-RS example)